# MySQL ROUND() calculates incorrectly

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am having the problem with MySQL `ROUND()` Function.
Here it is:

When I do this:

```
SELECT ROUND(7/2) as avg FROM bla blah
```

avg is 4

When I do this:

```
 SELECT ROUND(SUM(marks)/COUNT(marks)) as avg
```

avg is 3
Note: `SUM(marks)` on its own gives 7 and `COUNT(marks)` gives 2 which as far as I understand
`ROUND(SUM(marks)/COUNT(marks))` should be equal to `ROUND(7/2)`

What is the problem?

Comment: I tested on phpMyAdmin demo server online and both of the queries gave 4 as a result for me. my "marks" column is defined as int. what's your definition?

Comment: Not an answer but why not use AVG()??

Comment: Which datatype is `marks` and which `MySQL` version are you using?

Comment: Datatype is VARCHAR... I just noticed it. Thats must be the problem, need to inform the developers now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might use `CEILING` (same as `ROUND` except it always rounds to the bigger nearest integer)

```
SELECT CEILING(SUM(marks)/COUNT(marks)) as avg
```

should yield the result you want *for the requirements specified in the question*.

Comment: Hm... how about `select 4 as avg` to solve the current case? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently MySQL interprets `7/2` as `7.0/2.0` and does the calculation using floating point numbers instead of integers, giving the result `3.5` rather than `3`.

When you use `sum` the data type of the result is the same as the field, so you will be doing the calculation using integers, i.e. `7/2`, giving the result `3`.

Cast the values to `double` before doing the calculation:

```
SELECT ROUND(cast(SUM(marks) as double)/cast(COUNT(marks) as double)) as avg
```

Comment: You cannot cast to a floating-point type in `MySQL`, only to a fixed-point.

Comment: Hi, I tried this one, but I keep getting the error. It might be because of my marks datatype is VARCHAR.

Comment: @Nazar: that's because you should cast to a `DECIMAL`, not `DOUBLE`.

Comment: @Nazar: Then you have to convert the values to numbers before you can use `sum` on them.

Answer (score 0):

MySql mathematical operations create **float** results.

When using floats 7/2 could be represented as 3.4999999999999. Rounding that yields 3.

Comment: Hardcoded 7/2 is evaluated as 4 which is desirable result for me.
But when 7 comes from SUM(marks) and 2 comes from COUNT(marks) it evaluates as 3. If I do ROUND(SUM(marks)/COUNT(marks), 2) it gives me 3.50. I need it to be 4...

Comment: When it sees **7** as an integer constant it doesn't cast it to float, but when summing columns it can't know if the sum will overflow or not so it uses floats to begin with

Comment: If you need it to be 4, why do you just remove the `, 2` in the ROUND()?